# Dojo and UTC dates and times

Tags: dojo

is there a way to "force" dojo to show date and time in DateTextBox and TimeTextBox widgets in UTC independently of the SO configuration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot more than you want, but you could try requiring dojox.date.timezone and overriding the format to use a particular timezone (not sure offhand whether you could pass in a particular parameter through the widgets or if you'd have to do some monkey patching)  That's the more general solution, but I don't know if it's been tested.  The timezone code is still experimental.

You could probably fake something also by monkeypatching the method that does the display in the widget to subtract the offset from the time, but that wouldn't be "safe" for daylight savings, etc. , otherwise I think you'd need to go put conditionals in to use UTC accessors in the dojo.date code.